# How to link 2 tables so that changes in one tables would affect another

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

I have two tables in MS Access 2003. Both have some common columns. Is it possible that if I change the common data in one table it will affect another table. So I would not need to update the same data in each table. I tried to do that directly by typing the new values in sells and pressing SAVE button but it does not work (MS Access 2003).

Comment: Have you considered normalizing further?

Comment: Did you say foreign key?

Comment: I did not do anything special. My tables now are not linked to each other. I need to link them. How I can do that?

Comment: Normalize further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some Visual Basic that fires on the control's update event and copies, updates/and or appends, depending on what you are doing the value into the 2nd table.

I always find this code hard to figure out, and often have to spend half a day and dig through my vba (Visual Basic for Access) book but it will work.